# Eglot, Unnecessary Using Directive

Tags: eglot

```
   1 using System;
   2  
   3  namespace test.eglot
   4  {
   5      class Hukarz
   6      {
   7          public static void Main()
   8          {
   9              IFoo xyzzy = new Foo();
  10              Console.WriteLine(xyzzy.Bar());
  11          }
  12      }
  13 
  14      public interface IFoo 
  15      {
  16          public string Bar();
  17      }
  18      
  19      class Foo : IFoo
  20      {
  21          public string Bar()
  22          {
  23              return "quux";
  24          }
  25      }
  26  }
```

I'm now on Emacs-30 and I still can't get eglot to work.

With point on line 1, it says "unnecessary using directive" in the Echo Area, but when I go into *Messages*, I can't find this there, to be able to copy it.

When I compile it, it compiles without warnings

```
quasar in ﰬ2 ~/cs/poc/poc.eglot-endeavour via .NET v6.0.405  net6.0
BASHY $ dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  poc.eglot-endeavour -> /mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jhunterwu@gmail.com/insync-trash-merge-me/gd/gd/create/com/cs/poc/poc.eglot-endeavour/bin/Debug/net6.0/poc.eglot-endeavour.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.90
```

Can I get some more debug info why it says that?

EDIT; ok, it seems

```
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

has something to do with this;). I need to test a little more;)

I also wonder how I can copy this text that is displayed in the Echo Area.

Comment: To copy the text, go to the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: So what happens if you delete the first line? Maybe it's complaining that it's unnecessary because you are not using System.Console anywhere in the file. I'm just guessing, mind you.

Comment: What additional debug info do you want? These messages are generated by an lsp-server, whereas an lsp-server typically makes use of some kind of checker that you can run manually. In your case I presume you could just compile the code as usual with warnings enabled and you will get the exact same warning on the first line.

Comment: @NickD That message is not in *Messages*